# 2 orders with in 10 days in SQL

Tags: sql

Need SQL query to extract all the customer number
where
if a customer has ordered minimum 2 orders within the 10 days (between the 45 days)

Ex : between 01-01-2020 to 15-02-2020 a customer 1001 has order on 15-01-2020 and 20-01-2020, so this record we need to extract.

all the above requirement is in one table itself, custno, orderno, orderdate
INPUT TABLE

```
ORDERNO CUSTID ORDERDT
A1001 1001 20200115
A1002 1001 20200120
A1003 1001 20200130
A1004 1004 20200102
A1005 1004 20200130
A1006 1006 20200125
A1007 1006 20200127
A1008 1006 20200130
```

OUTPUT

EXPECTED RESULT

```
ORDERNO CUSTID ORDERDT
A1001 1001 20200115
A1002 1001 20200120
A1006 1006 20200125
A1007 1006 20200227
A1008 1006 20200130
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected result. A database tag is also needed (date functions are highly vendor specific): mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Comment: Have a look at `Lead`, `Lag` analytic functions (to get, say, prior order)

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS`:

```
with cte as (
  select orderno, custid,
    cast(cast(orderdt as char(8)) as datetime) orderdt
  from orders
)
select c1.* from cte c1
where c1.orderdt between '20200101' and '20200215'
and exists (
  select 1 from cte c2
  where c2.custid = c1.custid and c2.orderdt <> c1.orderdt
    and c2.orderdt between '20200101' and '20200215'
    and abs(datediff(day, c1.orderdt, c2.orderdt)) <= 10
)
```

This query uses the SQL Server function [`DATEDIFF()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), but you can use a similar function that works in your database. 
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=78e3212a0c66d3f527ac09689951db8a).
Results:

```
> ORDERNO | CUSTID | ORDERDT   
> :------ | -----: | :---------
> A1001   |   1001 | 2020-01-15
> A1002   |   1001 | 2020-01-20
> A1003   |   1001 | 2020-01-30
> A1006   |   1006 | 2020-01-25
> A1007   |   1006 | 2020-01-27
> A1008   |   1006 | 2020-01-30
```

Comment: Hi Sir,sorry for late reply. thanks for above solution but i am getting below error                                                       error : "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime"                             my field is date field is declared as -  (orderdt decimal(9,0), not null)

Comment: Your column is not date. You should declare it as date.

Comment: sorry, i didnt get you. my mistake. the table that i am using where the date field is declared, its declared as - orderdt decimal(9,0), not null.  note : its live table which i am fetching the data.     further the orderno and custid in our table is char only.       really sorry that i am highlighting now. new to this form.

Comment: Sir, thank a lot. it worked.  plz dont mind. data what ever is coming is correct but its also coming with extra data which i did not informed you in required.     the query is extracting the data even if a customer orders more than 2 order in a single day but we do not want this. we need the customer who ordered on different dates within 10 days. sorry last help for this requirement.

Comment: Sir, Thanks a million. hearty appreciate your patience help. its working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lead()` :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             DATEDIFF(DAY, ORDERDT, LEAD(ORDERDT) OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTID ORDER BY ORDERNO)) AS DAYS_DIFF
      FROM table t
     ) t
WHERE DAYS_DIFF <= 10;
```

Comment: Hi Sir,sorry for late reply. thanks for above solution but i am getting below error                                                       error : "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime"                             my field is date field is declared as -  (orderdt decimal(9,0), not null)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the original rows, you can use both `lag()` and `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
             lag(orderdt) over (partition by custid order by orderdt) as prev_orderdt,
             lead(orderdt) over (partition by custid order by orderdt) as next_orderdt
      from t
     ) t
where prev_orderdt > dateadd(day, -10, orderdt) or
      next_orderdt < dateadd(day, 10, orderdt)
```